# Selected Item Pivot for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, pivot, selecteditem

I have a problem selecting an item from a Pivot in Windows Phone 8.1. I have a CommandBar that makes navigation between pages belonging to Pivot, and have programmed change in the onClick SelectedItem of each button and the display changes to each page. When I start the application all the buttons, making debug SelectedItem change is made and no exception but the display does not change page. The strangest thing is that when I navigate manually between pages with navigation Pivot and then pressed a button on the CommandBar pages work. The problem only happens when I start the application.

It can happen ?, As I can solve ?, I'm a little frustrated xD.

Here is the code of Pivot and Command Bar:

```
<Pivot x:Name="pivotMain" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyleMain}" Margin="0,0,-0.333,0" >
        <PivotItem x:Name="pvtMenu" Header="Online" DataContext="{Binding Groups}">
            <ListView 
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListViewSection3"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding lstMenu}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StandardTripleLineItemTemplate}"
                    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
                    ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
            </ListView>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem x:Name="pvtMenuOffline" Header="Offline" DataContext="{Binding Groups}">
            <ListView 
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="itmListViewMenuOffline"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding lstMenuOffline}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StandardTripleLineItemTemplatePathImage}"                        
                    ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
            </ListView>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem x:Name="pvtInfo" Header="Información">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ListView>
                    <TextBlock Height="Auto" Width="Auto" FontSize="25"  Foreground="#7D7D7D">Encuéntranos en</TextBlock>
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,9.5,0,0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Image Source="Assets/fb.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="imgFcbk" Height="Auto" Width="300" Tapped="Image_Tapped"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,9.5,0,0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Image Source="Assets/tw.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="imgFcbk" Height="Auto" Width="300" Tapped="Image_Tapped_1"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,9.5,0,0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Image Source="Assets/yt.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="imgFcbk" Height="Auto" Width="300" Tapped="Image_Tapped_2"/>
                    </Border>
                </ListView>
                <Border Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="10">
                    <Image Source="Assets/componetes dispositivos moviles-22.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="imgFcbk" Height="Auto"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
<Page.BottomAppBar>        
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="barBtnHome" Label="Online" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" Click="barBtnHome_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="Assets/earth53.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="barBtnOffline" Label="Offline" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" Click="barBtnOffline_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="Assets/earth85.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="barBtnAbout" Label="Info" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" Click="barBtnAbout_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="Assets/appbar.information.circle.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

And here is the code behind the onclick:

```
    private void barBtnHome_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.pivotMain.SelectedItem = this.pvtMenu;
    }

    private void barBtnAbout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.pivotMain.SelectedItem = this.pvtInfo;
    }

    private void barBtnOffline_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.pivotMain.SelectedItem = this.pvtMenuOffline;
    }
```

Much appreciate your help.

Comment: try using SelectedItem instead of SeletedValue. Your Pivot Item might not have initialized completely when app first loads. SelectedItem should work

Comment: I'm using SelectedItem "this.pivotMain.SelectedItem = this.pvtMenu". How can i initialize the Pivot?.

Answer (score 0):

User SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem.

```
private void barBtnHome_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.pivotMain.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void barBtnAbout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.pivotMain.SelectedIndex = 1;
}

private void barBtnOffline_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.pivotMain.SelectedIndex = 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yout answer. I also tried it, but it has the same error.